# Reformat lvm to ext4 and change mountpoint

Tags: partition, lvm, ext4

I need the space of sda on either `/` or a specific mount like `/data`. How can I repartition / change the current layout to match the needed desire?

`sda                          8:0    0  2.7T  0 disk
├─sda1                       8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                       8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                       8:3    0  2.7T  0 part
  ├─centos_hosted--by-root 253:0    0   50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos_hosted--by-swap 253:1    0 15.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos_hosted--by-home 253:2    0  2.7T  0 lvm  /home`

fstab

```
/dev/mapper/centos_hosted--by-root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=428e7c4c-d50a-45cc-ac2e-ab7f21e39a69 /boot            xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/centos_hosted--by-home /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/centos_hosted--by-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

The partition should be `ext4`. `/home` is empty so it wouldn't care if it has to be wiped.
Is it possible to archieve it without reinstalling the whole server?

Comment: Why does it have to be a *new* partition and specifically ext4-formatted? Can't you just shrink an existing filesystem, `lvreduce` the LV it's on, then `lvextend -r` the existing `/` LV?

Comment: Oh, scratch the "shrink" part: XFS cannot be shrunk. Still, delete `/home` and extend `/` without creating a new partition?

Comment: @n.st, my understanding is OP want `ext4` filesystem. And `root` is `xfs`

Comment: @RomeoNinov I understand they want ext4, but I'd like to know *why*. Not to be rude, but from the question I get the impression that OP doesn't know much about the differences between filesystems, so they might be asking for ext4 without a technical reason.

Answer (score 1):

THe process is sample (if `/home` is fine to be destroyed)
Exec following commands (**as root**)

```
umount /home
lvremove /dev/mapper/centos_hosted--by-home
#if the name of volume group is centos_hosted--by
lvcreate -n centos_hosted--by-data -L 100G centos_hosted--by 
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/centos_hosted--by-data
mkdir -p /data
mount /dev/mapper/centos_hosted--by-data /data
```

Edit `/etc/fstab` and replace `/home` with `/data` and `centos_hosted--by-home` with `centos_hosted--by-data`. Also change `xfs` in this line with `ext4`

If you want to see the name of volume group exec command `vgs`